# Parametros nomeados na url - asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou com um problema na geração automática de url junto ao Asp.NET

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
[RoutePrefix("c")]
[Route("{action=Index}")]
public class ConteudoController : BaseController
{
    [Route("{urlConteudo}")]
    public ActionResult Index(string urlConteudo){ ... }
    [Route("{urlMenu}/{urlConteudo}")]
    public ActionResult Index(string urlMenu, string urlConteudo) { ... }
}
```

No momento de gerar a url uso o seguinte trecho de código

```
Url.Action("Index", "Conteudo", new { urlConteudo= "titulo-teste", urlMenu = "noticias" });
```

Mas o resultado do parametro nomeado não é o esperado.

Esperado:

> /c/noticias/titulo-teste

O que realmente teve de saída:

> /c/titulo-teste?urlMenu=noticias

Obs.:
No meu RouteConfig eu tenho o mapeamento de atributos de rota

```
 routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new string[] { "TesteRotas.Controllers"}
            );
```

O que exatamente faço para alcançar o resultado das rotas nomeadas?

Comment: Ainda não consegui ver o que a saída lhe mostra mas, já tem um erro aqui de digitação `new { urlConteudo= "titulo-teste, urlMenu = "noticias" }` o correto seria `new { urlConteudo= "titulo-teste", urlMenu = "noticias" }`

Comment: Realmente foi um erro de digitação @VirgilioNovic mas no caso eu reamente não consigo fazer a criação da url pelo Helper o questionamento persiste

Comment: Descobri o problema, era um conflito de rota.

No caso a rota mais específica estava ficando por último e o ASP.NET sempre para na primeira rota que se adequar.

[Route("{urlConteudo}", Order = 1)]

No Index com apenas um parametro eu adicionei o valor de Order para que ele ficasse depois do outro na tabela de rotas e resolveu (:

Answer (score -1):

Vou utilizar o campo de respostas pois ainda não posso comentar.

O que você está fazendo com o trecho é mandar dois atributos pela URL, você pode:

1- utilizar os atributos desta forma (puxa informação da URL pra uma variavel):

```
Request.QueryString["atributo"];
```

2 - atualizar o seu routeconfig.cs , tente:

```
  new { area ="", controller = "Home", action = "Index" },
  new { area = "^$", controller = "Home", action = @"(Pagina1|Pagina2|etc..)"}
  new string[] { Home.Controllers }
```

Comment: No caso não seria bem isso, pois eu teria de ter um único action pra determinar e eu não conseguiria usar o Url Helper do Asp.Net pra que ele gere as urls.